# Как назвать дальнего предка?

Tags: лексика

Она изучала каждого входящего, в надежде хоть мельком увидеть Такера, прапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрапрадеда Франка и Дианы.

Можно ли как-то заменить двадцать приставок пра-, на пращура, предка и как это связать с количеством поколений?

Comment: "Предок в двадцатом колене" не подойдет? Или вы что-то другое имели в виду?

Comment: Если » в двадцатом колене» точно предполагает двадцать поколений, отсчитанных назад, то подойдёт. Вы меня просто выручили. Спасибо.

Comment: Именно так. Подробнее - см. мой ответ. А откуда такой странный текст? Фантастика? Я не могу представить живым и входящим, человека обзаведшегося потомками через 20 поколений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю, поскольку там дискуссия пошла...
Я полагаю, что тут точнее сказать именно "в NNN-м колене".
Разницы, действительно, смысловой нет, но для таких выражений конструкция "в третьем/шестом/двадцатом колене" устоялась. Выражение "до седьмого колена" хорошо знакомо всем, кто разбирался с библейскими текстами (в частности, евреям предписывалось, знать имена своих предков именно "до седьмого колена"). Давид, опять же, - предок Иисуса в сороковом колене... Ну и много еще подобных примеров.

Кроме того, как-то так сложилось, что "поколение", если и используют, то отсчитывают "вниз" по генеалогическому древу, то есть для потомков, а слово "колено" настраивает на обратный отсчет.

ПС. Я впервые столкнулся с тем что кто-то (Ожегов - согласно Римма Михайлова) рекомендует для этого значения р. мн. - "кол**ё**н". Современный словари этого не делают. Попробую уточнить. Но для вас это не принципиально.

Будьте внимательны, если это принципиально. Количество "пра" в русском языке не равно числу колен. Прадед - это предок в третьем колене. Прапрадед - в четвертом. И так далее.
Боле точное соответствие дает понятие "троюродный", "четвероюродный" - и далее. Троюродный дословно "имеющий с кем-то того же предка в третьем колене (прадеда), Четвероюродный - в четвертом (прапрадеда). Правда, дальше "семиюродных" в русском языке уже не считают - ибо тяжело представить, а на "колена" такого органичения нет.

Comment: С **ё** у Ожегова можно не утруждаться — это просто опечатка (я ее тоже видела, но в комментарии — по времени — с этим невозможно было разобраться). Ожегов: **колено** —  8. (мн. -колена, -ен). Разветвление рода, поколение в родословной (устар.). Родня в седьмом колене. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/85526

Comment: У меня там по-аглицки 19штук great и grandfather(дед), в общем, принцип отсчёта поняла. Детское фэнтези про эльфов и пр. Еще раз пересчитаю. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, так подойдет?
**Она изучала каждого входящего в надежде хоть мельком увидеть Такера, предка Франка и Дианы в двадцатом поколении.**

Вот подобное предложение.
*У Майи мгновенно сработала эйдетическая память изощрённых в дворцовых интригах десяти поколений предков* (В. Звягинцев. Мальтийский крест).

Теперь о запятой, вернее, о ее отсутствии перед "в надежде".
[НАДЕЖДА](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0) — **в надежде, с надеждой** [надеясь].
*Сделавши это распоряжение, Анна Павловна возвращается восвояси в надежде хоть на короткое время юркнуть в пуховики* (С.-Щ.).

*Женихи собирались у ограды ее дома и прогуливались перед крыльцом **в надежде хоть мельком увидеть** эту прелестную девушку* (Х. Дэвис. Мифы и легенды Японии).
*Разумеется, к дому Френчей ежедневно прибывали любопытные, которые околачивались там целый день **в надежде хотя бы мельком увидеть** загадочную женщину...* (Э. Гилберт. Убийство в назначенный срок. Длинная тень смерти)
*Зная, что полиция уже прочесала окрестности, она все же внимательно осматривала улицы **в надежде хоть мельком увидеть** беглого пациента* (Т. Герритсен. Эксперимент).

Если хочется сделать паузу, то, думаю, лучше поставить интонационное тире.
Она изучала каждого входящего — в надежде хоть мельком увидеть Такера...

Comment: Спасибо, так в поколении или колене? Какая между ними разница? Не могу найти примеров такой конструкции. Наверное, потому что фэнтези.

Comment: В словаре Ожегова: **колено** —  8. (мн. колена, -ён). Разветвление рода, поколение в родословной (устар.). Родня в седьмом колене. http://endic.ru/ozhegov/Koleno-12548.html У Дмитриева: 11. Коленом называют поколение в родословной. Свою родословную он знал до шестого колена. // Глобальной разницы нет. Главное, чтобы Вас поняли (сейчас про особенное колено не каждый знает).